# Active Directory / Exchange: Convert User + Email into Only Shared Email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, active-directory

I want to convert an exchange user account / email to just a shared email with an access group.

**Scenario:**

I have a windows active directory network with a user account called "mydomain\bob".  I can log into computers and Outlook Web App (OWA) because I created an email when I made it: bob@mydomain.net

However, I want to treat "bob" as a shared email, normally this should be pretty easy I assume, but to make it more difficult, I cannot delete the user account (and start with just an email) because I need to preserve all emails (unless I could somehow export them all and then import).  So in PowerShell I did: "Set-Mailbox bob -Type:Shared"

I also don't want anybody to be able to log into a computer with "mydomain\bob", I only want them to get into Outlook Web App.  How can I remove the "bob" account from the "bob" email on the exchange server without deleting "bob"?

I'm following [this tutorial on making a shared email in OWA](http://knicksmith.blogspot.com/2007/03/exchange-2007-and-shared-mailboxes.html) and I have a group called "Mail Access Group" that I want to add people to, to give them mail access, but this command fails:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Add-ADPermission 'bob' -User:'Mail Access Group' -ExtendedRights:Send-As -AccessRights:ReadProperty, WriteProperty -Properties:'Personal Information'
There are multiple objects matching the identity "bob". Please specify an unique value.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Add-ADPermission], ManagementObjectAmbiguousException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 509FB2E4,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.AddADPermission
```

*Update*

I managed to temporarily change the "Name" field and and it allowed me to run the command.  I disabled the account originally related to the email (on the domain server), and the email is still active.  However, I can't seem to add the mailbox via OWA under any of the users in the access group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

1. Change the email group to Shared.
2. Make sure that changing the email group to shared, disabled the uer account.  If not, disable.
3. In order to run the "Add-ADPermission" command to allow group access permissions, temporarily change the email account's "Name" field in the GUI admin, run the command.
4. Wait a few hours for propagation (of course you will also have to add users to the access group).